# PHP XML to Array

Tags: php, arrays, xml

EDIT: The reason I used json_decode is to get it from XML to an array.

So here is my dilemma:

I access an API that returns xml, I then convert it to an array as follows:

```
public function convertXMLtoJSON($xml){
        return json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($xml), true), true);
}
```

When I have a single item (for example:) [SINGLE ITEM XML]

```
 <LineItem>
       <field>hello</field>
 </LineItem>
```

It gets displayed like: [SINGLE ITEM ARRAY]

```
[LineItem] => Array(

     [field] => hello

)
```

now if I have: [MULTI ITEM XML]

```
 <LineItem>
       <field>hello</field>
 </LineItem>
 <LineItem>
       <field>hello part 2</field>
 </LineItem>
```

I get: [MULTI ITEM ARRAY]

```
[LineItem] => Array(

         [0] => Array (

             [field] => hello

         )

         [1] => Array (

             [field] => hello part 2

         )

)
```

I need the first example to be in an array, not just by itself because differentiating between the two is just going to be way too time consuming.

Comment: `json_decode(json_encode(...))` Why?

Comment: To your point about "*too time consuming*", you could just `if ( count($arr) > 1) { // multiple elements } else { // single element }`

Comment: Just check to see if the value is an array or not. If it is, pull it apart (or do an implode); if it's not, take the value.

XML to JSON conversion will only put things in arrays when there's more than one of them. If it did it every time, then every single element would be in an array, and that would be even more uglier.

Comment: Frankly, converting XML to JSON is a bad idea in general, and really should be avoided. Why not just use SimpleXML and use object oriented traversal to find your elements? JSON is a totally unnecessary step.

Comment: What is your desired format for the second case? Note that arrays must have unique keys.

Comment: @KeithTyler I needed to get an array out of it, and that was the simplest method I found.

Comment: You have a sample array of what you get now, but can you post a sample array of what you want to have instead?

Comment: @colonelclick I just updated it. But basically I want everything to look like a multi item array. If I have a single item it looks like the single item array, I need them all to be uniform.

Comment: @jerdiggity not even close

Comment: @user298329 You can just slurp the XML text into a SimpleXMLElement and then use object notation. So e.g. `$root=SimpleXMLElement($xml); $array_of_field=$xml->xpath('//field');`

http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand your specific question, you want everything to be formatted like the multi array, even if there is only a single result.

I would handle this by checking the array for a count of 1 after it is returned. Let us suppose that you have an array called $xmlArray that has a single result in the format you describe.

```
if (count($xmlArray) == 1) {
    $multiArray['LineItem'][] = $xmlArray['LineItem'];
}
```

This will convert the $xmlArray with a single element into the multi-line array format you have described in your question.